# How to check the docker is installed by apt-get in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, apt-get

I can install the docker with `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` in Ubuntu. I read the script, and find if the previous `docker` is not installed by `apt-get install docker-engine`, there should be trouble.

To improve the script, I want to terminate it if the `docker` is not installed by `apt-get`.

How can I know whether the `docker` in installed by `apt-get`?

```
Warning: the "docker" command appears to already exist on this system.

  If you already have Docker installed, this script can cause trouble, which is
  why we're displaying this warning and provide the opportunity to cancel the
  installation.

  If you installed the current Docker package using this script and are using it
  again to update Docker, you can safely ignore this message.

  You may press Ctrl+C now to abort this script.
```

Answer (score 8):

`apt-get` is mostly for installing and updating.
List you installed docker packages with `sudo dpkg -l | grep docker`

I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: If the user build a private docker, and install manually. The docker will not appear in the `dpkg -l`?

Comment: True. In that case,  a simple `which docker` command should do the work.